# What should I use in place of Select-AzureSubscription?

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-cmdlet

I am trying to remove deprecated cmdlets in a powershell script and one of the cmdlets is `Select-AzureSubscription`. I tried replacing it with `Select-AzureRmSubscription` but that requires user interaction to authenticate. Does anyone know what `Azure-Rm` cmdlet I should be using instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Select-AzureRmSubscription` does change the approach that Azure uses for authentication. I had the same pain points when I converted my scripts.

The official way of approaching this via scripting is as follows -

```
$profile = Login-AzureRmAccount 

Save-AzureRMProfile  -Profile $profile -path $path
```

You can then use `Select-AzureRmSubscription` to none-interactively load those saved profiles.

Although ultimately I didn't go this route, I decided to add another layer of security and use a machine based certificate to encrypt / decrypt credentials to pass to `Login-AzureRmAccount` This way I could manage multiple sets of accounts and never have to be concerned about those tokens being exposed on vulnerable machines.